# "Argument of \pgfmath@@onquick has an extra }" when using pgfmathsetmacro or pgfmathtruncatemacro with &&-operator inside tabular

Tags: tables, pgfmath

When I run the following code...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\pgfmathsetmacro\foo{(2<3) && (3<4)}
\foo
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get

> ERROR: Argument of \pgfmath@@onquick has an extra }.

If I use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, I get the same error. However:

- If I delete the `tabular` environment, it works fine.
- If I replace the operation with `and((2<3),(3<4))`, it works fine.
- If I use `\pgfmathparse...\pgfmathresult`, it works fine.

Is there a fix for this? Clearly the problem is that `tabular` is somehow reading `&` as a row separator. (Currently, I use `and` instead of `&&` in all my `pgfmath` code, for fear that my macros might be eventually put inside a `tabular`.)

Comment: You can hide it from tabular via extra braces `{\pgfmathsetmacro\foo{((2<3) && (3<4))}\foo}`

Comment: @percusse Looks like the core of an answer to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pgfmathsetmacro` uses a `\begingroup` `\endgroup` group for its calculations which isn't enough to hide `&&` from tabular, you *could* redefine it to use `{` instead but no promises that that doesn't break something else in pgf.

This works though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathsetmacro#1#2{%
%\begingroup
{%
\pgfmathsetlength\pgfmath@x{#2}%
\edef#1{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfmath@x}}%
%\pgfmath@smuggleone{#1}\endgroup
\expandafter}\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\pgfmathsetmacro\foo{(2<3) && (3<4)}
\foo
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```